# How can I write a for loop (in matlab) that makes each row into an individual struct?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, struct, cell

I currently have a 102 x 80 x 2 matrix (102 subjects x 80 trials x 2 sessions). I would like to make each row of this matrix into it's own struct. So in the end I would like 102 x 2 structs (102 subjects and 2 sessions). Within each struct there should be 80 x 1 rows.

How can I write a for loop that separates each row into its own struct?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `num2cell` to convert each row into cell and then `deal` to fill up the struct:

```
% random data 
X = rand(102,80,2);
% convert each row into a cell
Y = squeeze(num2cell(X,2));
Y = cellfun(@transpose,Y,'UniformOutput',0); % transpose matrices
% initalize struct with desired size
s = struct([]);
s(size(Y,1),size(Y,2)).data = [];
% assign struct values
[s(:).data] = deal(Y{:});
```

[image]

Comment: Yus! This works! Thanks so much for the instructions and the code!

Comment: If it's not too much, could I also ask you how you would then transpose each of the structs? Because ultimately I need a 80 x 1 rather than a 1 x 80.

Comment: sure. just add `Y = cellfun(@transpose,Y,'UniformOutput',0);` after `Y = squeeze(num2cell(X,2));` - I edited my answer as well.

Comment: Great! This works! Thanks so much. Hope you have a blast today!

Answer (score 0):

Well it can be done with a few lines of code and without a `for` loop

```
% Define matrix
mat = rand(102, 80, 2);
% Define indices for the new struct matrix
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:2, 1:102);
% Make a struct with your data
mat_struct = arrayfun(@(x, y) struct('data', mat(x, :, y).'), Y, X);
```

Here mat_struct will be a 102x2 array with the data field each of which contains 1x80 matrix

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it! 

I just tried this out and it does give me a 102 x 2, with a 1x 80 matrix. 

You'll have to excuse me for lack of understanding of the code. But is there a way to transpose the matrix so that I would get a 80 x 1 matrix instead?

Comment: Yes! You're amazing. Hope you had a splendid day!

Comment: Its nice to be of help :)